# Sending push notification using ionicframework cloud api

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Hello am trying to send push notification from my nodejs server to ionicframework API and am getting an error here is my code

```
var token = '66a5c472b52d3210b591f717b5b996312f8xxxxxxxxxxxx';
var title = 'test';
var message = 'message';

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  json : {
    "send_to_all": true,
    "profile" : "my-profile",
    "notification": {
      "title": title,
      "message": message,
      "android": {
        "title": title,
        "message": message
      },
      "ios": {
        "title": title,
        "message": message
      }
    }

  }
};

request(options, function(err, response, body) {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);
  console.log(body);
});
```

am getting this error

```
{ error:
```

{ message: 'JWT decode error occurred.',
     link: null,
     type: 'Unauthorized' },
  meta: 
   { status: 401,
     version: '2.0.0-beta.0',
     request_id: '75726406-3060-4329-a59e-3bd7f9ca90c8' } }

What could I be doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue  with your authorization header. 
In header you're putting token, but please make sure it is API token.
Also make a postman request first and check whether it is working fine.
add content-type and authroization parts in header only..

then check the difference..

Thanks
Basu